# .NET Core Publish Task Slow on Agent

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a CI pipeline which builds and publishes .NET Core 2.1 project. On my PC when I try to publish with `dotnet.exe publish` in Command Prompt, it takes about 1-1.5 minutes max. However with the agent on a separate VM, the publish task takes over **3-4 minutes**.

[image]

I have disabled `Publish Web Projects` hoping it affects but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Microsoft-Host agent it takes some time to spin up.  Each request gets a new/clean VM.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much time it would save (if any), but I typically put the "--no-build" argument in my dotnet publish command since it's already built.

Comment: Thank you... I added the `--no-build` in the publish arguments and sadly it still takes so much time.

Comment: @naregkar - sorry that didn't work.  The only other thought I had was that you have the "zip published projects" marked.  If the publish command can take over a minute locally (and you probably are not zipping it there), then maybe it's the compressing of the files that is taking so long.

Comment: Yes, I had already tried that and the difference is just 10-15 seconds. It seems I have to accept the fact that it takes a bit of time.. thanks anyway :)